# Connect to SQL Server using python jdbc

Tags: python, sql-server, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a local instance of SQL Server using python jaydebeapi. But I receive an "AttributeError: type object 'java.sql.Types' has no attribute '**javaclass**' " error

I am using windows OS with JDK 14 & JRE 1.8.0_241

```
import jaydebeapi
conn = jaydebeapi.connect("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver","jdbc:sqlserver://SS2019;databaseName=AdventureWorks;integratedSecurity=true;", "/PATH/mssql-jdbc-8.2.2.jre8.jar")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use cx_oracle module to connect to SQL server. Import cx_oracle first than can provide the credentials of the server to connect

Comment: (a) The question is about SQL Server, not Oracle. (b) Even if this were about Oracle, just mentioning a library isn't a very good answer. Please read [answer].